# jquery resize, keep comments position relative to image

Tags: jquery, css, resize, position

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6cmmd7jq/)

I created a script to allow users to comment on top of an image.  The img is responsive but the comments on top of the img and not.  When i resize, the comments stay at their original top and left positions, and I can not get them to keep their respective positions.  I uploaded a jquery fiddle for you to see.  I could really use your help!

```
var oldHeight = $('#proofNow').height(),
    oldWidth = $('#proofNow').width();

$(window).resize(function() {
    var parent = $('#proofNow'),
        parentWidth = parent.width(),
        parentHeight = parent.height();

    $("img.TDot").each(function(){
        var top = parseInt($(this).css("top")),
            left = parseInt($(this).css("left")),
            topRatio = oldHeight / top,
            leftRatio = oldWidth / left,
            newTop = parentHeight / topRatio,
            newLeft = parentWidth / leftRatio;

        //console.log('top: ' + top + ', left: ' + left);
        $(this).css("top", newTop);
        $(this).css("left",newLeft);
    });

    console.log(parent.width());
});
```

I'm guess my math is wrong, but I still can not figure it out.  I need to be able to go both ways

Answer (score 0):

I am confused why do you need Javascript for this? What is preventing you from letting the browser do the hard work, and use CSS/Html.

Css Block

```
div {
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width="60%"
}
```

Html Block

```
<div>
   <div name="comments"> ... </div>
   <img src="..." />
</div>
```

Comment: All main div has a position relative, and all the comments are set to absolute, but they are still not moving and keeping the relative position.

Comment: Consider this, layout changes can mostly and almost always accomplished with CSS and HTML. Disregarding the actual css rules posted, you should be able to come up with an html layout and css ruleset that accomplishes the style you are looking for.